# Deploying and Update Process of On Premise Kubernetes Environment Application

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, microservices, updates

We are developing a microservice based system that is orchestrated using Kubernetes. Part of our use case is supplying our clients an On-Premise installation where they receive an Image (VMDK / QCOW2) with all the system deployed.

One of our main challenges is handling the update process of such system, currently the plan is to have an API endpoint that will receive an encrypted and signed package that will contain all the images and a certain update shell script. The API endpoint will start an asynchronous process that will extract the images and execute the shell script that eventually should call the Kubernetes to update all the images with the new code.

The question is where this API endpoint should be defined?

1. Be in a special "Maintenance" service that will be outside of the Kubernetes and control it, this service will be updated last in case it's code should be also updated.
2. Be part of one of the microservices containers that run inside Kubernetes - but then this image can be part of the updated images so any API that should return the update status can be un-available

What is the common way to export an interface to System Update or System Deployment wizard processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the client's on-prem systems reach a service you control over the Internet?  The Kubernetes-native way to do this would be for you to run a public-facing registry server with some sort of client-specific authentication.

Comment: No , the plan it to expose an API that will allow a client to upload the images from a disk-on key, they will be copied into the local repository and applied.
The question is where this endpoint should reside?